# How to forecast 10 days ahead using CNN-LSTM. I used the WTI data

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm, prediction, forecasting

I am using WTI DATA from US website. I am using CNN-LSTM model for prediction and forecasting. My problem is that I can't understand how to forecast 10 days ahead. I have run all of this program with no error. I am using Jupyter notebook in Python. Prediction and graphs are successfully run.

My program:

```
import numpy
import pandas

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
# load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/python/WTI.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print(len(train), len(test))
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
dataX, dataY = [], []
for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
dataX.append(a)
dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 2
# split into samples

# reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]


trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
n_features = 1
n_seq = 1
n_steps = 1

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, testX.shape[1]))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None,1, look_back)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
MAE = mean_absolute_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0])
print(MAE)
trainMAE = mean_absolute_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0])
print(trainMAE)
testMAE = mean_absolute_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0])
print(testMAE)
trainmape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0])
print(trainmape)
testmape= mean_absolute_percentage_error(testY[0],testPredict[:,0])
print(testmape)
# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict
# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict
# plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How can I find 10 days ahead forecast using this code. My model is CNN-LSTM.